# Wrap a set of divs with the same style

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a set of `divs` containing different styles within a `div`. I want all those which match a certain class to be wrapped in a parent `div` programmatically. How can we implement this? Any ideas?

Comment: post some code, what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)  or [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) for that in jQuery:

```
$( ".class" ).wrap( "<div class='parent'></div>" );
```

If you could post some code, at least you html, I would be easier to find an answer wich fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Good ol' jQuery (haters gonna hate):

```
$("<p>").wrap("<div></div>");
```